# ng-content vs router-outlet in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to know, which is better approach of doing

**i.** using **ng-content** in parent component and later when creating child component, make the child component enclosed in parent's selector.

eg : I would like to create a parent view as component .
a. LandingComponet (Parent):

```
<div> 
Website Landing view 
....
...
<ng-content></ng-content>
....
...
<footer></footer>
...
</div>
```

b. LoginComponent or RegisterComponent (children components)

```
<app-landing>
<div>
Login view or Register view
...
</div>
</app-landing>
```

c. adding separate routes for all children component

```
{ path: '', component: LandingComponent },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }
```

**ii.** use **router-outlet** in the parent component and make more than one children route in the routing file.
eg : I would like to create a parent view as component .
a. LandingComponet (Parent):

```
<div> 
Website Landing view 
....
...
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
....
...
<footer></footer>
...
</div>
```

b. LoginComponent or RegisterComponent (children components)

```
<div>
Login view or Register view
...
</div>
```

c. Add routers in the app.routing.ts

```
{
path: '',
component: LandingComponent,
children: [ 
 { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
 { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }
]
}
```

Both has pros and cons, which to stick is a problem for me,

> I personally like second(ii.) approach, any heads up will help me to
>   take decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, both are totally different from each other, or either we can't say that you can use `ng-content` where `router-outlet` needed.
basically

> ng-content

is used when we have to wrap some content in another component, hardly `ng-content` is used up to 2 or 3 level deep components.
Also, you can style to `ng-content` etc. but

> router-outlet

is used when we have to configure routing structure for the app.

when we have to load many/no of components in a single outlet.

Also, I would suggest not to use `ng-content` in your use case instead use `router-outlet`.

Comment: This answer needs clarification.  I don't know what "when we have configure routing structure" really means or has to do with this.  Please clarify.